# header like facebook with fixed width

Tags: html, css

Hello expert i am trying to build a welcome page like facebook. I want a header with different color with fixed width with browser just like facebook welcome page. I have created a div id with 100 width. But the width is not fitting with the browser. it showing in the body. Please tell me how to do this. I am absolutely new in all of this.

**Index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="welcome.css"/>
<title>Welcome To The Thinkers</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header"><h1>Welcome To Thinkers</h1></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    background-color:yellow;
    width:100%;

}
p{
    font-size:23px;
    color:#930
}
.header{width:100%;
height:72px;
background-color:green;

}
```

Comment: Just use `position:fixed` on your `.header` CSS - example here - http://jsfiddle.net/3ajjM/

Comment: Just look the stackoverflow site's top bar. where username seache box has. i want to build that type of top bar. how to do it.?

Comment: First: learn the basics of html and css. Second: learn how to inspect the code of other sites using development tools (in Chrome, or Firebug in Firefox). Third: show some effort instead of asking for a direct solution. Fourth: a late welcome to stackoverflow.com :)

Comment: @oyshee Stackoverflow's top bar is completely different to Facebook's one. Facebook's one is fixed position and follows you when you scroll, StackOverflow's doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly I think your problem is with default margin/padding on certain elements.

If you add

```
body, h1
{
  margin:0; 
  padding:0;
}
```

It should sort that out.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Jv4VT/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
//these code is for fixed header
.header{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left:0;
width: 100%;
background-color: #0683c9;
}
```